# Setting vertex ID in Titan 1.0.0

Tags: graph-databases, titan, tinkerpop3

My app is currently using Titan 0.5.4 as its graph DB and does the following -

Parses a given raw data, then creates a vertex containing the parsed data, and also creates a unique identifier using a combination of the input data fields.
Later on, when querying the graph, it re-creates the same unique identifier in order to check if data already exists (and fetching it).

I am currently working on a migration to Titan 1.0.0,
and I cannot find a way to set vertex IDs as before.

How do you set a vertex ID on Titan 1.0.0?

A possible workaround is to create an indexed property (so-called id2), but it seems redundant to me.

Thanks

Comment: What does your Titan 0.5.4 code look like, that is, what API were you calling on to create the vertex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the titan transaction still allowes you to provide an id when creating the vertex. 
Note, this might be a bug and might be removed in the next version.
https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/blob/titan10/titan-core/src/main/java/com/thinkaurelius/titan/core/TitanTransaction.java

I think a reasonable way to solve this is to add a property key and composite index on each of your vertices and use that for your queries.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to say that you cannot set the vertex ID in Titan as it is generated on construction. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10322041/why-cant-i-set-the-id-for-a-new-vertex-using-gremlin-in-java) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17397466/how-to-overwrite-vertices-id-in-titan-database) are questions which ask the same thing essentially.

In Titan's case I believe that the id refers to an actual location on the disk). As stated [here](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/0.5.0/data-model.html):

> The (64 bit) vertex id (which Titan uniquely assigns to every vertex) is the key which points to the row containing the vertex’s adjacency list

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a property which can be indexed to provide the same functionality?